# Do cascoded MOSFETs need to be in their own wells in order to properly connect bulk to source?

Tags: cmos, layout

I am learning to design CMOS layouts. When creating the layout for something like a cascoded current mirror, are individual wells needed to properly connect the bulk to source?

For example, for the cascoded current mirror seen in figure 1, does there need to be 3 individual p-wells? M1 and M2 are both source to ground, so they can go in the same well in order for bulk to be connected to source/ground. However, the sources of M3 and M4 are connected to the drains of M1 and M2, respectively. Do M3 and M4 each need to be in their own individual wells such that bulk can be connected to their source/the drains of M1 and M2?

[image: Figure 1: Cascoded Current Mirror]

Figure 1: Cascoded current mirror.

Comment: How do your Vts vary with channel length? A very short channel for the upper FETs may be very useful approach.

Answer (score 1):

No. That would make cascoding too onerous to be so widely used.

You would have to account for the body effect in your calculations but the principle and the advantages remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need separate P-wells. In "normal" CMOS proceses the P-well isn't even separate, it's the P-substrate and shared between **all** NMOS transistors:

[image]

As long as you connect the P-substrate to the lowest potential (usually ground, which is the case in your circuit) then the NMOS drain and source regions will be reverse biased as they will be at the same or a higher potential.

So M3 and M4 share the same P-substrate with M1 and M2 and that's OK. M3 and M4 will have an increased Vt due to their source not being at the same potential as the substrate (Body effect).

So the complete cascoded mirror you show will share the same P-substrate. There do not need to be separate P-wells and often the IC manufacturing process doesn't even allow it.

Some (triple-well) processes do allow for separated P-wells but for a current mirror there would be no point as it would increase the layout size and make device matching worse.